# zfs cache disk for the block device, any performance advantage?

Tags: zfs

I plan to create ZFS pool with **cache** option:

```
zpool create .. raidz1 /dev/... cache sdX1
```

and then ZFS with **-V** (-V means block device will be created)

```
zfs create -o compression=off -o dedup=off -V 13....
```

Question:
ZFS cache device affects performance in case of creating **block** device?

My OS: debian 9.5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The cache device works for volumes as well as datasets if that's the question. If the addition if a cache device translates to a performance advantage for your particular use case that's a different question and can't be answered with the information provided.

Comment: by volumes you talking about block devices (created with -V option)?

Comment: Yes, called volumes or zvols.

Answer (score 0):

L2ARC works for *both* datasets and volumes. Truth to be tell, ZVOLs are little more that "hidden" files with some specific block abstraction - and they sit atop of the DMU (just as regular datasets with regular ZPL).

That said, it is not possible to predict *if* and *how much* the additional L2ARC will benefit your workload.